# MySQL Summing with an algebraic expression for every row

Tags: mysql, select, sum

Let's just get right to it.

This returns the right result:

```
SELECT sum(w.weight * w.repetitions)
FROM workout_exercise_logs w
JOIN workout_logs wo ON `w`.`workoutLogID`=`wo`.`workoutLogID`
JOIN workouts wor ON `wo`.`workoutID`=`wor`.`workoutID`
WHERE w.weightType=1 and `wor`.`userID`=34
```

But when I add `+ w.weight * w.seconds / 3`, I get a `NULL` result:

```
SELECT sum(w.weight * w.repetitions + w.weight * w.seconds / 3)
FROM workout_exercise_logs w
JOIN workout_logs wo ON `w`.`workoutLogID`=`wo`.`workoutLogID`
JOIN workouts wor ON `wo`.`workoutID`=`wor`.`workoutID`
WHERE w.weightType=1 and `wor`.`userID`=34
```

What's wrong with the expression and how can I fix it? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A question, should you really need this field be nullable(or any fields for that matter): seconds ?

If that is a requirement, you need to coalesce those nullable fields to zero:

```
SELECT sum(
      w.weight * w.repetitions 
      + w.weight * coalesce(w.seconds,0) / 3)
FROM workout_exercise_logs w
JOIN workout_logs wo ON `w`.`workoutLogID`=`wo`.`workoutLogID`
JOIN workouts wor ON `wo`.`workoutID`=`wor`.`workoutID`
WHERE w.weightType=1 and `wor`.`userID`=34
```

Comment: also you can use IFNULL instead of coalesce.

Comment: @MajidTaheri Thanks, I was not able to recall that function name immediately. I know in Sql Server, it's ISNULL. But I certainly know that coalesce works on virtually all database platform ツ

Comment: yes [IFNULL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull) is in MySQL